# In Matterjs project, is there solution to make sync the motion of the bodies in different OSs and browsers?

Tags: matter.js

I'm working on Matterjs project. I have already built project on Windows10. But it works difference on another OSs and Browsers. If you have a great experience, please let me know the solution.
I'm looking for hearing from you.

If possible, I will be happy if you share your previous project's source code with your answer in detail.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What is different, exactly, and which OSes and browsers are you referring to? A [mcve] of your code would be good, along with specific problems. As far as I know, things should be pretty much the same, with monitor refresh rate being the major difference between systems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.